# load Property after ProcessBuilder is executed

Tags: java, properties, processbuilder

I have a method that executes a batch file through ***ProcessBuilder***. After the batch file is executed, the contents of an ini file saved locally will be updated.

After ProcessBuilder executes, I then need to load the ini file to get the properties because I need to return it as JsonObject.

I've been able to do all of this. My issue is that the properties that I am getting are the contents of the ini file from the last execution of the ProcessBuilder not the current. To get the contents of the ini file from the current execution of the ProcessBuilder, I have to reload my url which would then call the batch file again.

My question is that how should I load my ini file properties so that it would get the updated values after the batch file has been executed?

This is my method:

```html
public void identify() throws IOException {

  ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","StartSample.bat");
  builder.directory(new File(PATH));
  Process process = builder.start();
  BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
  r.close();

  
  Properties p = new Properties();
  p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/PV/PVInfo.ini"));
 String pvidNO1 = p.getProperty("PVIDNO");
 String pvidNo2 = p.getProperty("PVIDNo");
 String pvidNo3 = p.getProperty("PV-ID");

 

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("PVIDNO", pvidNO1);
 jsonObject.put("PVIDNo", pvidNo2);
 jsonObject.put("pvId", pvidNo3);
 System.out.println(jsonObject);
   
  
 }
```

Hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Seems using [process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) could be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following snippet would work as you expect.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "StartSample.bat");
builder.directory(new File(PATH));
Process process = builder.start();
process.waitFor();

Properties p = new Properties();
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/PV/PVInfo.ini")) {
    p.load(fis);
}
String pvidNO1 = p.getProperty("PVIDNO");
String pvidNo2 = p.getProperty("PVIDNo");
String pvidNo3 = p.getProperty("PV-ID");
```

from the [process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) javadoc

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.

Comment: Should I still keep my load properties code or should I follow yours? Because I'm getting an error on this line _(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/PV/PVInfo.ini"))_ it says : **Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7**

Comment: @Kylie For your question related to `Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7`: Are you still on Java below version 7? If possible think about to upgrade. If an upgrade is not possible you need to handle the close of the `FileInputStream` yourself.